# Write every element in list in a specific order

Tags: python

**I want to write everything in a list exept first element.** 
 So I made a command prompt type of script and made three files: main.py, commands.py and tasks.txt

Here is main.py:

```
import commands

while True:
    text = input("> ")
    text_split = text.split(" ")

    commands.run_command(text_split)
```

And here is commands.py:

```
def run_command(args):
    if args[0] == "add":
        with open("tasks.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(args[:1])
```

When I run this code

```
add - Test Task
```

I expect this in my text file:

```
- Test Task
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

How can I fix this and get a efficient code?

## Thanks

### Sab

Comment: Note: your example shows the list with only the first element (`args[:1]). Your question and example output suggest `args[1:]`. Please double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
file.write(" ".join(args[1:]))
```